# Loading collada into 3D view of QGIS using Qgis2ThreeJs Plugin?

Tags: qgis, 3d, model, qgis2threejs, three-js

I have been looking at documentation and other posts but cannot find a way to load a 3D model into QGIS.

I Installed the qgis2ThreeJs Plugin.

I have tried to load a collada file in a temporary scratch layer. The Geometry type was Point.

After adding the layer I launch the threejs plugin.

Then I can go into the point layer properties and set the Shape to "3D Model". Then you can select a model file. After closing the properties, I do not see any model in the 3D view.

Comment: Please decide which format you wish to ask about in this particular question. That way you can tell us precisely what you tried and where you are stuck.  You can always ask about another format in a separate question.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I load a .dae model but it does not show anything. Some models work but most do not... I exported some sketchup models as .dae and it is the same...